# Removing the overlaps between time range and updating values accordingly in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble eliminating the overlaps in my Date/Time variables. I'd like to replace my Date/Time values accordingly to remove all the overlaps in the timeline. For example, my data looks like this:

```
StartTime                  EndTime
 2018-09-17 11:00AM     2018-09-17 12:00PM
*2018-09-17 12:00PM     2018-09-17 01:00PM*      
*2018-09-17 12:30PM     2018-09-17 01:00PM*     
 2018-09-17 01:00PM     2018-09-17 02:00PM 
*2018-09-17 02:00PM     2018-09-17 02:30PM*
*2018-09-17 02:00PM     2018-09-17 03:00PM*    
 2018-09-17 03:00PM     2018-09-17 04:00PM
```

As you can see, there are some overlaps between the time periods (rows with **) and I want to adjust either StartTime or EndTime value to avoid the overlaps. For example, I want to get the final table that looks like this:

```
StartTime                  EndTime
 2018-09-17 11:00AM     2018-09-17 12:00PM
*2018-09-17 12:00PM     2018-09-17 12:30PM*      
*2018-09-17 12:30PM     2018-09-17 01:00PM*     
 2018-09-17 01:00PM     2018-09-17 02:00PM 
*2018-09-17 02:00PM     2018-09-17 02:30PM*
*2018-09-17 02:30PM     2018-09-17 03:00PM*    
 2018-09-17 03:00PM     2018-09-17 04:00PM
```

In some cases, the EndTime (e.g. the first overlap in this data) needs to be modified and sometimes the StartTime (e.g. the second one) needs to be adjusted. My current code only works for the first case and doesn't capture all the overlaps in the data.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT StartTime, 
       LEAD(EndTime,1) OVER (ORDER BY StartTime, EndTime) AS NextStartTime
FROM myTable
)
SELECT StartTime,
       CASE WHEN EndTime > Next_StartTime THEN Next_StartTime 
       ELSE EndTime END AS EndTime
FROM CTE
```

I know it seems very complicated and the data itself is pretty messy but I can't really make changes in my raw data itself. I'd appreciate any help on this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the logic for determining which column should change?  Your description is indeterminate.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, the logic behind it is that the time range should be continuous within the same date (.e.g. 2018-09-17). So for the first overlap, if you just adjust the EndTime from 1:00 PM to 12:30 PM, I can remove the overlap and the time values would be continuous without any break. (e.g. 12:00 PM - 12:30PM / 1230PM to 1:PM).   But if you see the second overlap between 2PM and 3PM, if you just fix the Start time of  2PM to 2:30, the data would be continuous without any break or overlap.

Comment: Plus, I'd say for the data to be continuous, the end time of the current row should be equal to the start time of next row. But the important thing is, if the time is broken down into a less than hour unit, I'd like to catch all these small chunks instead of breaking the time into hours. For example,  something like "*2018-09-17 12:30PM     2018-09-17 01:00PM*" should be captured as a separate unit instead of making it into *2018-09-17 12:00PM     2018-09-17 01:00PM*

Comment: Hi - you don't appear to have actually described the logic that needs to be applied. There appear to be 3 options:

1) Always adjust the start date to line up with the end date of the previous row
2) Always adjust the end date to line up with the start date of the next row
3) Adjust either the start or end date based on some logic you need to clearly define.

Also, when you say "continuous within the same date", can the start and end dates of a record overlap midnight and, if they can, does this affect the logic you need to be applied?